# Django: serialize json as a parameter when redirecting to external url

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I am trying to redirect a user to a Facebook app once they login to my Django application. This is happening from inside my view. The Facebook app is expecting a Json encoded variable. Here is what I am trying (which is not working):

```
json_data = serializers.serialize("json", UserProfile.objects.filter(user=user), fields=('study_code'))
url = "https://www.facebook.com/" + json_data + "some_other_stuff"
return redirect(url)
```

My question main question: What is the proper way to do this?

One issue I am having is that the "json_data" variable is returning the following:

```
[{"fields": {"study_code": "XXX001"}, "model": "django_app.userprofile", "pk": 12}]
```

I thought the 'fields' parameter, in the serialize method, will limit the returned data to only the specified field (I only need the study_code) but I'm getting all of this extra stuff. Also, I can't append the 'json_data' variable to the string 'url' (obviously). What is the correct way to append this serialized data to the url string?

Comment: you're concatenating it with a string, so I don't think you want to be using json formatted data. What is an example url that you are trying to redirect to?

Comment: Facebook wants json formatted data. The example I was given was: https://www.facebook.com/$json/some-other-stuff where the variable json is what is returned from the php method json_encode.

Comment: try using json module and simply using `json.dumps({"study_code": user.study_code})`

Comment: Also, I point out that I am incorrectly trying to append this to a string and that this is obviously not the way to do this. I'm asking what is the proper way to redirect to an external url when one must insert json encoded data into the url? :)

Comment: I've never heard of an api looking for json encoded data in the url, and not as post data.

Comment: I tried `json.dumps` as well, but the Facebook app is unable to recognize the URL. When doing essentially the same thing in PHP (using `json_encode`) it all works. The python `json.dumps` and php `json_encode` seem to be pretty similar and they are the suggested replace function when switching languages.